# How to loops to column in dataframe in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

i am the newone with pandas, can i loops 2 column by position 1 and 3 in pandas dataframe below

```
import pandas as pd
inp = [("tokyo",8,7),("new york",6,8),("sydney",4,7),("london",12,7)]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=inp,columns=["a","b","d"])
print(df)
```

the result will bee like this

```
tokyo
7
new york
8
london
7
```

Thanks you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
lst = [x for y in zip(df['a'], df['d']) for x in y]

for item in lst:
    print(item)
```

Output:

```
tokyo
7
new york
8
sydney
7
london
7
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have to loop, which is slower, you can do this

```
df[['a','d']].stack().reset_index(drop=True)

0       tokyo
1           7
2    new york
3           8
4      sydney
5           7
6      london
7           7
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the output, what you can do is to loop through row, then use only selected columns

Example:

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    print(row['a'])
    print(row['d'])
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also do this way:

```
s=''
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    for key,value in row[:].items():
        s+=str(value)+" "
        if key=='b':
            pass
        else:
            print(s)
        s=''
```

output

```
tokyo 
7 
new york 
8 
sydney 
7 
london 
7
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
result = pd.Series(df.iloc[:, [0,2]].to_numpy().flatten())
```